# IP Address Not showing up in Serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, serilog

I have setup Serilog with .net 6 asp.net core project but the IP Address is not showing up in the logs using the json formatter.

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithClientIp()
    .Enrich.WithClientAgent()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

And I have setup my appsettings like this. But I'm not sure why the IP Address is not showing up in the logs for any request (get, put, etc.)

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File, Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId", "WithClientIP", "WithClientAgent" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "===> {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C://Temp//appLog_.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 4194304,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 10,
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: did you added `AddHttpContextAccessor();` to your services ?

Comment: Note: IP data is considered personal information and subject to regulations like GDPR. So any data leak can lead to lawsuits. e.g. [read this](https://www.optimizesmart.com/ask-these-eight-questions-to-make-your-server-logs-gdpr-compliant/)

Answer (score 0):

In Program.cs, I change the code into below code:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));
...
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
{
    // Customize the message template   
    options.MessageTemplate = "{RemoteIpAddress} {RequestScheme} {RequestHost} {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} responded {StatusCode} in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms";

    // Emit debug-level events instead of the defaults
    options.GetLevel = (httpContext, elapsed, ex) => LogEventLevel.Debug;

    // Attach additional properties to the request completion event
    options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
    {
        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestHost", httpContext.Request.Host.Value);
        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestScheme", httpContext.Request.Scheme);
        diagnosticContext.Set("RemoteIpAddress", httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);
    };
});
```

Read [net6.0 Serilog example](https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example#5-wire-serilog-into-the-webapplicationbuilder) and [Adding IP logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/38) to know more.